# How to log into remote servers?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I currently have a VBScript that reads a list of servers, and attempts to verify the password of a specific userid.  The userid is locally on that server. I am checking to see that the password is not set to the default (I want to make sure it was changed to something else).

The "list of servers" can be a mix of IP addresses, hostnames (like Rocky), or fully qualified DNS names (like rocky.bigcompany.com).  The servers are a mixture of physical and virtual devices, and may or may not be on a domain.

The existing VBScript I wrote handles all this, and works fine.  I'm trying to re-write this same program in Powershell, and It's not working.

Here's the function I have in VBScript that does what I want:

```vb
Function LoginToServer(Computer, username, password)
    'this function will log into a server

    On Error Resume next

    Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set wmi = locator.ConnectServer(computer, "root\cimv2", username, password)

    'check the error code and see if we logged in successfully
    LoginRC = Err.Number

    If LoginRC <> 0 Then
        msg = "Could not log into server: " & CStr(computer) & " With ID: " & CStr(username)
        lfo.lmsg "B", "WARN", msg
    Else
        msg = "Server: " & CStr(computer) & " Logged in successfully as: " & CStr(username)
        lfo.lmsg "B", "INFO", msg
    End If

    wmi.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3

    'return the code back to calleer
    LoginToServer = LoginRC
End Function
```

… and here's what I've tried to do in PowerShell:

```bsh
Param($ComputerName = "LocalHost")

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Actual Code starts here
Write-Host "Attempting to ping server: $ComputerName"
$IPResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Quiet

if ($IPResult -eq "TRUE") {
    Write-Host "Ping OK - now attempting to log in"

    try {
        $ID = "userid"
        $PSW = "password"

        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $PSW -AsPlainText -Force
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ID, $password)
        $sesh = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error caught"
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    } finally {
        $Time = Get-Date
        "$Time Computer: $ComputerName ERROR: $ErrorMessage ITEM: $FailedItem" |
            Out-File c:\temp\TestCredScript.log -Append
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Could not ping server"
}
```

How do I log into these remote computers with an ID and Password using PowerShell?

Comment: Can you be more specific than `It's not working`? :)

Comment: Sorry Mathias - In my zeal to get all the information I could into the post, I realized last night that I hadn't given any detail about what wasn't working..  When I try to use the code to log into a server that is not on the domain, I get an error saying that I've used an invalid ID or password.  I know the ID and password were valid.  I logged into the server just after running the code, to verify that that I had the correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two code samples do different things. The VBScript code connects via WMI whereas the PowerShell code tries to establish a PowerShell session. For the latter you need [PowerShell Remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) enabled, which you probably don't have.

While you probably may want to enable PSRemoting anyway, you can also use WMI from PowerShell. The [`Get-WmiObject`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) cmdlet allows you to provide credentials and impersonation level, so you don't need to establish a connection first like you need to do with VBScript (if you want to use explicit credentials).

Example querying the `Win32_Process` class on a remote computer:

```
$computer = '...'
$username = 'userid'
$password = 'password'

$pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)

Get-WmiObject -Computer $computer -Namespace 'root\cimv2' -Class Win32_Process -Impersonation 3 -Credential $cred
```

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.05.powershell.aspx) for further information.

Comment: thank you!  You've kept me from getting premature baldness!  I originally tried to do something like this, but could not get it to work.  I have to look at some of the code I saved, but I think I was trying to hard-code the password into PSCredential instead of using Convert-To-SecureString first.  I gave up and tried other methods I'd seen elsewhere, and ended up frustrated and posting the code you saw.  I have modified my script using the information you've provided, and it now works great!  Thanks for helping a newbie Powershell scripter!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to accept the answer.  I'm new to posting on this forum, and still figuring things like this out as well.